# How to enable Just My Code (Threads View)? Visual Studio 2012.

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio

I am reading this article on msdn
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983998%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I have no ideea how to do this in Threads window. I assume that has nothing to do with Debuging-> General -> Enable just My Code from the Options window.

Where is the damn thing? I want to disable unimportant infomation from the thread call stacks (.Net calls).

Comment: That's in the Concurrency Visualizer, not for normal debugging, is that what you're using?

Comment: No! Is this feature available in visual Studio 2012 premium? If yes, how can I open it ?

Comment: It's on the `Analyze` menu from the main window ...

Comment: Thank you ! Aparently that was the hidden feature. Anyway collecting trace from there is imense. It is now to a staggering value of 2.0 GB, and is still going.